# Outlet vs outlet collection

Tags: swift, xcode6

In xcode 6.1 when i drag a button from the main.storyboard to the specified viewcontroller.swift file i get 3 options. 2 of which are outlet & outlet collection. Can somebody explain to me what's the difference between them ?

Answer (score 13):

OutletCollection is collection of outlets!

Guess You have multiple label All which Have same text to display!then you just have to define one outletCollection and connecting all outlets to that outlet. whenever you change text of your outletCollection All label's text are changed  and so on!

if you are making simple game(like game of ZombieHunt),then you need multiple images for every zombie!

In short by changing only outlet collection you can change state of all outlets!
i hope you understand what i want to say!

[possibly Duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374488/whats-the-difference-between-outlet-connection-and-action-connection)