# How to define text in UILabel from a variable? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to programming in general and want to know how to do this. I am making a simple app in which I need to keep track of a score and update a `UILabel` accordingly. The label is named **'score'**. I need it to increase by one as the user presses a `UIButton`. Does this involve making new .swift files? Remember that I am a complete newbie to this.

Answer (score 2):

dont need new swift files, in your viewcontroller that has the UILabel, define a variable for the score

```
var scoreValue = 0 //define in the class, next to your score label probably
```

then when you need to update the label, in some function that gets called when you push the button do something like

```
scoreValue += 1 //increase scoreValue by 1
score.text = "Score: \(scoreValue)" //labels text will look like "score: 1"
```

Answer (score 2):

No. You don't have to make any new .swift file. Below code will explain how to do it and try to add your code relevantly.

```
var score = 0 //declare in class level
```

//button click action

```
@IBAction func ButtonClick(sender: AnyObject) {

        score+= 1
        scoreLabel.text = "Score : \(score)" //this will display the score increased by 1.
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by adding an IBOutlet to your label and an IBAction to your button.

[image: Add an IBAction]

You can select if it's an Outlet or action in the dropdown menu. Next, update your label in the IBAction function!

[image: Update Label]

I hope this helps to get you started!

Oh, and welcome to programming! :)

Comment: BTW, you can create an IBOutlet / IBAction from the Storyboard control + dragging to your class!

Comment: How can I do this if the button and the label are on different view controllers (ViewControllerA & ViewControllerB)? Would I need to have multiple .swift files here(ViewControllerA.swift & ViewControllerB.swift)? Because it would not let me create the outlet for the label when it wasn't on the same view controller.

Comment: @AidanHouston yup an `@IBOutlet` can only be hooked up to the class file associated to the `UIViewController`in the interface builder. You can change the class of a view controller using the Identity Inspector in your storyboard file.

Answer (score 1):

So the goal here is to respond to an "action" with an event that increments the value displayed on label. So we need to break this down into a few different parts.

1. We need to have the event/action
2. We need to increment some sort of counter
3. We need to update the labels value with the value of the counter.

For number 1, you will want to look into creation an "[action](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingAction.html)" in the "Interface Builder" in Xcode. You will also want to use a similar approach for setting the label as an "[outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374488/what-is-the-difference-between-outlet-connection-and-action-connection)". We will call the label "lblScore"

For the 2nd you will want to declare a [variable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID356) which will hold the counter. Lets call this variable "count" so:

```
var count = 0
```

Now, you will want to add incrementing the counter within the action that you set up in number 1. You can do that, in Swift, via:

```
count += 1
```

This will add 1 to the current value of count. Now, all you need to do is update the value of the label, to be the current value of "count".

But wait, the value of "count" is an "int" and the "text" property of the UILabel takes a "string"! This means you need to "[cast](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)" the value to string. In this same, you would do:

```
lblScore.text = String(count)
```

Taken all together, it would look like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var lblScore: UILabel!

var count = 0;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@IBAction func addScore(sender: AnyObject) {

    count += 1

    lblScore.text = String(count)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

I hope this helps!